# regular expression goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, regex

I am parsing (species) names of the form:

```
Parus Ater
H. sapiens
T. rex
Tyr. rex
```

which normally have two terms (binomial) but sometimes have 3 or more.

```
Troglodytes troglodytes troglodytes 
E. rubecula sensu stricto
```

I wrote

```
[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s+[a-z][a-z]+(\s*[a-z]+)*
```

which worked most of the time but occasionally went into an infinite loop. It took some time to track down that it was in the regex matching and then I realised it was a typo and I should have written

```
[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s+[a-z][a-z]+(\s+[a-z]+)*
```

which performs properly.

My questions are:

- why does this loop happen?
- is there a way I can check for similar regex errors before running the program? Otherwise it may be difficult to trap them before the prgram is distributed and cause problems.

[Note: I don't need a more general expression for species - there is a formal 100+ line regex specification for Species names - this was just an initial filter].

NOTE: The problem arose because although most names were extracted precisely into 2 or occasionally 3/4 terms (as they were in italics) there were a few false positives (like `"Homo sapiens lives in big cities like London"`) and the match fails at "L".]

NOTE: In debugging this I have found that the regex was often completing but being very slow (e.g. on shorter target strings). It is valuable that I found this bug through a pathological case. I have learnt an important lesson!

Comment: You can't simply predict if a regex will enter an infinite loop. If you have too complex regexes ("100+ line regex"), it might be (I say "might") that you need some kind of parser instead.

Comment: I think you should write `(\s+[a-z]+)+` instead of `\s+[a-z][a-z]+(\s+[a-z]+)*`

Comment: @shift66 I wrote `\s+[a-z][a-z]+` because I wanted to make sure the second term had at least 2 characters. I don't care about the third and later.

Comment: @dystroy This is a very simple regex. You mention a parser - where can I find one?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: Take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)

Comment: You should read up on catastrophic backtracking (which is your actual problem - not an infinite loop: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and the Halting problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem.  Since Regular Expressions are essentially descriptions of a finite state machine to parse a string, you cannot create a general solution which predicts which regular expressions will backtrack catastrophically, and which will not.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Thank you. This seems to be the answer. If you add it as such I will accept it. But any hints about how to detect it in practice would be valuable even if they are heuristic.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan, I agree that it should be catastrophic backtracking. But I don't see how that expression would backtrack catastrophically for that input. Nor any input. The second term should never backtrack if any part of the 3rd fails. And the regex for the 3rd+ term(s) should backtrack as much as `(\s*[a-z]+)?`. Unless of course OP has something more after this expression.

Comment: I think that's because `(\s*[a-z]+)*` may lead to more than one interpretation : even for a simple string, the engine can follow many paths here.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan maybe the best comment I've seen on SO.

Comment: @dystroy, that doesn't matter in this case. For this expression when it comes to `(\s*[a-z]+)*` it will: 1) try to match `\s*[a-z]+`, 2) match it and goto 1), or 3) fail to match and thus 4) succeed matching the full expression. Thus no nested/catastrophic backtracking should happen. Unless OP has something more following this expression in his real use case.

Comment: @Qtax - I assume it's non matching characters.  Assume the string `"I love the number 9!"` Appears.  The parser will match up to the nine, then just start backtracking like mad.  The parser will keep back tracking, over and over and over again, trying to find a way to make it match past the nine.  Remember, with `\s*` it can back track all the way until the minimum match of the expression before the group: `[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s+[a-z][a-z]+` can match just `"I lo"`, then `(\s*[a-z]+)*` can match `"v"` all the way to `"ve the number "` in a crazy number of ways.

Comment: @d'alar'cop Glad you like it.  Working on an answer version right now.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan, why would it do that? The expression isn't anchored. Or does OP use some Java function which anchors the expression? That could be the case, but OP should mention this then.

Comment: @Qtax  Yes, he probably should.  It'd also be nice to get some sample data he's actually matching against to see exactly where the issue occurs - probably best with the actual code being used to do the matching.  (Hint, hint, peter, for posterity's sake).  Regular Expressions questions generally don't have enough information - don't you find that most people underestimate the importance of factors outside their actual expression?

Comment: @Frankie. See above. But it took a little while to find the offending target string.

Comment: @Frankie What does "anchor" mean?

Comment: I've linked to http://www.regular-expressions.info so many times on this page, I feel borderline plagiaristic, but here's another: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html Anchors are **Zero width assertions** (Regular expressions that don't consume any actual characters) that define the position in the string.  Most commonly:  `^` is used for the beginning of the string (or line), and `$` is used for the end.  I usually group `\b` in there as well, which denotes a word boundary (beginning or end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address the first part of your question, you should read up on [catastrophic backtracking](http://regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).  Essentially, what is happening is there are too many ways to match your regular expression with your string, and the parser is continually back tracking to try and make it work.

In your case, it was probably the nested repitition:  `(\s*[a-z]+)*` Which likely caused some very very strange loops.  As Qtax has adeptly pointed out, it's hard to tell without more information.

The second part of your question is, unfortunately, impossible to answer.  It's basically the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Since Regular Expressions are essentially of a finite state machine whose input is a string, you cannot create a general solution which predicts which regular expressions will backtrack catastrophically, and which will not.

As far as some tips for making your regular expressions run faster?  That's a big can of worms.  I've spent a lot of time studying regular expressions on my own, and some time optimizing them, and here's what I've found generally helps:

1. Compile your regular expressions outside of your loops, if your language supports it.
2. Whenever possible, add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) when you know they're useful.  Especially the `^` for the beginning of the string.  See also:  [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
3. Avoid nested repetition like the plague.  If you have to have it (which you will), do your best to provide hints to the engine to short circuit any unintended backtracking.
4. Take advantage of flavor constructs to speed things up.  I'm partial to [Non-Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).  They don't appear in every flavor, but when they do, you should use them.  Also check out [Atomic Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)
5. I always find this to be true: **The longer your regular expression gets, The more trouble you're going to have making it efficient.**  Regular expressions are a great and powerful tool, they're like a super smart hammer.  [Don't fall into the trap of seeing everything as a nail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).  Sometimes the string function you're looking for is right under your nose.

Hope this helps you.  Good luck.

Comment: Number 4 is sufficient here. Number 1 is unrelated to the backtracking hell. Anchors is also unrelated and should only be added when it is necessary. Number 3 is quite useful in some cases, but is still susceptible to backtracking hell problem.

Comment: @nhahtdh You are incorrect, as three is the solution to this particular problem.  Four, though extremely helpful, is not a general solution to the problem of which regular expressions will and won't catastrophically backtrack - especially because not all RegEx flavors support them.  Anchors can be incredibly useful when avoiding catastrophic backtracking.  Look at the performance of `\bx+y` in comparison to `x+y` when matching an arbitrarily long string of Xs. I wasn't trying to provide a map to debugging all catastrophic backtracking - just give some ideas on how to avoid inefficient RegEx.

Comment: Possessive quantifiers are syntactic sugar for atomic groups, which Java has support for. For my own expressions I always use these where possible.

Comment: They're syntactic sugar, but they're so much easier to read.  Really, you should know what you're using and exert as much power as possible.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: I stand corrected about number 3. After analyzing the regex myself as I write the answer, changing the logic of the regex a bit does help. However, as it stands, your advice for number 3 is not practical. A more practical suggestion would be to write a grammar for the text that you want to validate, then write the regex for it, or find good assumption about the input string to apply to the regex. As for the anchor, I am not sure where and when your suggestion applies.

Answer (score 3):

For the first regex:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*\.?\s+[a-z][a-z]+(\s*[a-z]+)*
```

The catastrophic backtracking happens due to `(\s*[a-z]+)*` as pointed out in the comment. However, it only holds true if you are validating the string with `String.matches()`, since this is the only case where encountering an invalid character causes the engine to try and backtrack, rather than returning a match (`Matcher` loop).

Let us match an invalid string against `(\s*[a-z]+)*`:

```
inputstringinputstring;

(Repetition 1)
\s*=(empty)
[a-z]+=inputstringinputstring
FAILED

Backtrack [a-z]+=inputstringinputstrin
(Repetition 2)
\s*=(empty)
[a-z]+=g
FAILED

(End repetition 2 since all choices are exhausted)
Backtrack [a-z]+=inputstringinputstri
(Repetition 2)
\s*=(empty)
[a-z]+=ng
FAILED

Backtrack [a-z]+=n
(Repetition 3)
\s*(empty)
[a-z]+=g
FAILED

(End repetition 3 since all choices are exhausted)
(End repetition 2 since all choices are exhausted)
Backtrack [a-z]+=inputstringinputstr
```

By now, you should have notice the problem. Let us define `T(n)` as the amount of work to check a string of length n does not match the pattern. From the method of backtracking, we know `T(n) = Sum [i = 0..(n-1)] T(i)`. From that, we can derive `T(n + 1) = 2T(n)`, which means that the backtracking process is exponential in time complexity!

Changing `*` to `+` **avoids the problem completely**, since an instance of repetition can only start at the boundary between a space character and an English alphabet character. In contrast, the first regex allows an instance of repetition to start in-between any 2 alphabet characters.

To demonstrate this, `(\s+[a-z]+\s*)*` will give you backtracking hell when the invalid input string contains many words which are separated with multiple consecutive spaces, since it allows multiple places for a repetition instance to start. This follows the formula `b^d` where `b` is the maximum number of consecutive spaces (minus 1) and `d` is the number of sequences of spaces. It is less severe than the first regex you have (it requires at least one Englsh alphabet and one space character per repetition, as opposed to one English alphabet per repetition in your first regex), but it is still a problem.

Comment: +1 Very useful. I probably use this construct when I shouldn't. It would be useful to have a "lint" that suggested when you do poor things