# Jenkins bug while creating new job?

Tags: regex, jenkins

i would ask you to check something, because I am not sure if it a Jenkins bug or if it has to do something with our internal settings. Please tell me if you are faceing also exceptions when using upper-cases within the job name.

**Bug description:**

When I press the button "create", the tomcat cpu usage explode directly to 99% on the Jenkins server, the configuration page for the new created job is never displayed and stop the browser from loading has no effect to the CPU usage.

After recognizing that i wanted to check some more details and went to the monitoring page. 
I use the [Monitoring](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring) plugin for Jenkins. And what i found was a thread within the "Current requests" that was running all the time... named "checkJobName". 
I killed it manually and the server went back to normal.

**Reason:**

Reading "checkJobName" made me think of something which leads me to the solution: When I want to create a new job everything is fine as long as the job key only contains lower-cases.
When I fill in upper-cases I always ran into the bug described above.

**Solution:**

Before facing this bug my company used a regular expression to restriced job names. Under Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Restrict project naming we had the following RegExp:

```
\bcom.mycompany.\b[a-z0-9]+(([\-]?[a-z0-9]+)+|([\.]?[a-z0-9]+)+)*+$
```

But it seems like this was not checking the whole word, because still uppercases were allowed when using names like "com.mycompany.test.myUpperCaseTest". To avoid the bug above i changed the RegExp so that only lower-cases are allowed:

```
\bcom.mycompany.\b[a-z0-9]+(([\-]?[a-z0-9]+)*|([\.]?[a-z0-9]+)*)*$
```

Comment: How do you restrict job names in Jenkins? I couldn't find a way, but I did find a popular plugin that creates views using a regex pattern. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing a [catastrophic backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15919146/7586), maynly because of the nested loops and optional `[\-]?` and `[\.]?`. This is usually painful when the pattern does *not* match, as you've experienced.

Use this pattern instead:

```
^com\.mycompany\.[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

- escape dots. You don't want `com!mycompany?job`
- `[a-z0-9]+` - one word.
- `(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more words. Before each word there is a period or a hyphen.

Comment: you are using "?:[.\-]", but doesn't that mean ever letter is allowed, followed by a slash? 
We dont want to allot every single letter. We want to accept only names startet with "com.mycompany." and followed by lower-case letters, numbers, dots and - (e.g.: test.group-09).
Everyything else should not be accepted

Comment: @Krummy - No, it doesn't mean that - `.` has no special meaning inside a character class (`[…]`), and the backslash is used to escape the hyphen which *does* have a special meaning (like in `[a-z]`: `-` is special). Please test the pattern, I think it should do exactly what you ask (and not use 100% CPU).

Comment: works for me! 
Thank you a lot for your help and your explanations! :)