# Is there any problem with this regex expression?

Tags: regex, timeout

Is there any problem with this regex expression? ,it always gets a timeout result when it matches the string，here is a example string:sdkjfksdjfkjskdfjksdjfkjsdkfjskdjfsdf=,I think it is supposed to return a result of match or not match,but actually it returns a timeout result,I don't know what is the problem,and here is the regex expression:

```
/^[a-z0-9]((-?[a-z0-9]+)|(\.?[a-z0-9]+))*$/
```

Comment: Whats' your string? What error your get in Console ?

Comment: There isn't any error, some online web tools show it is timeout, and when it runs in my Vue project, the page gets crashed.Here is a test string: sdkjfksdjfkjskdfjksdjfkjsdkfjskdjfsdf=

Comment: Could yoy please edit your question. Add a string, regex, and your's Expected Output.

Comment: Hi, I have had  edited the question

Comment: Your editing is not very helpful. use https://regexr.com/ to show what problem you're facing

Answer (score 0):

The information you gave is absolutely sufficient to show what problem you're facing. Some regex testers report that a time limit is exceeded, a Python `re.match` is running seemingly endlessly until eventually killed. It seems your expression is suffering from exponential complexity; the question [*regular expression goes into infinite loop*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919146/regular-expression-goes-into-infinite-loop) has answers with advice how to avoid such a problem. If I'm not mistaken, your given expression can be simplified and freed from the problem by replacing it with

```
^[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I replaced the expression with another one, and the problem was solved. Maybe you're right, the wrong expression goes into infinite loop when it matches.